# Transaction Library of OpenEJB

Tags: tomcat, transactions, jta, openejb

We have a project and we need a transaction mechanism for business logic. In the current phase of the project we will not use full OpenEJB (simply, because it's not an option atm-we use source which would need a complete overhaul-eventually we might do that, but not for the moment).

Because the already established source runs on Tomcat 6 and we might eventually in the process of the big overhaul port it to Tomcat 7 I was wondering if we could use only the part of OpenEJB which provides transactions in order to make the transition to full blown OpenEJB later easier-For the moment manual tx handling is quite all right.

So the question is: Which is the library that OpenEJB uses to provide JTA and does it run on Tomcat 6?

Rudi

Comment: As long as you work with a single DB, I do not consider the step of switching to JTA (instead of resource local transacations) important for your future migration.

Comment: Actually we want to use JTA for Transactions which book/cancel requests per xml, depending on the outcome of the whole transaction.